# How to use b3 to create a local mirror of the stuff I need?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

I'm using some 3rd party libraries to create my RCP application. These libraries are available as update site / p2 repository, and they are provided by eclipse (e.g., the RCP target, EMF) or by a third-party repository. Accordingly, I've created a target file to describe what I'm using to build my application.

Due to a recent outage of one of these repositories, I want to have a local mirror of all the stuff I'm using to build my application. Somebody told be to look at b3, but I need some additional help. Following the tutorial, I've copied from my target file the p2 repositories and created some validation rules (according to the feature I use).

However, when I start the build, it mirrors huge parts of the eclipse's indigo repository (including, for example, the JDT, WTP, and linuxTools, which are NOT required directly or indirectly by my RCP app).

Is it possible to limit the mirror to the features listed in my target file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only the Helios version of b3 installed (not sure how it works in a newer one, but probably its similar), there I can add some child items to the Mapped repository elements to add an **exclusion rule** to remove some items, or add some specific **features** or **plugins**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried to use exclusion rules to remove non-interesting items: sadly the eclipse repository (indigo) includes too many items, so I have to write a lot of exclusion rules. Conversely, I tried to add the features and the plugin listed in my target file into the b3's configurations. In this case I made some mistakes because several plugins were "forgotten" (e.g., the stuff for the binary distribution of the eclipse RCP was missing, even if the "org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" feature was listed). Does there is any tutorial / guide / something on b3?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know of any tutorial - this is quite a new project, and the original goal wasn't the creation of a repo mirroring tool but a build automatization tool. Maybe instead of the Indigo repository you could use smaller, project-specific repositories. In this case, the mirroring should be faster, and more importantly, easier to modify.